# How can I edit the following command to print two columns?

Tags: templates, columns

and I found a pretty template, but the problem is that one part of this is too big and I want to split into two columns.

The part when the CV template make an entrylist is the following:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

I want to create two columns and inside of the columns put a lot of entrylist, I tried with `\begin{multicols}{2}` but doesn't work and I don't know how to make that works

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to MWE (Minimal Working Example) which we can test as it is. Clarify, if this table should be longer than one page?  Ate text in the second column  can has more than one line?

Comment: Where is `\headingfont` defined? And do you really want to redefine `\bfseires`?